# Data not updated in room db after sorting alphabetically

Tags: android

i'm using mvvm architecure in my app and it is working fine , my issue is i'm trying to order data alphabetically after click on navigation drawer item , the view is being updated but after restarting the app the order is gone which means that the data is not being updated in room db itself , i tried many ways to fix that but nothing worked out for me.
Here is my piece of code :

** Query to order the data alphabetically

```
    @Query("SELECT * FROM taskstable ORDER BY model_task_name")
    LiveData<List<MvvmModel>> SortAlphabatically();
```

** This is the piece of code which updates the view and supposedly should update data in room db as well

```
      case R.id.sortalphabetically:
      viewModel.repository.SortData.observe(MainActivity.this, new Observer<List<MvvmModel>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<MvvmModel> list) {
            mvvmAdapter.UpdateRecycler(list);
                 }
                    });
                 break;
```

Any help would appreciated , thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't change the order of data inside database, you can sort the data only using `query`.

Comment: well yeah im using query to sort the data and then update , that"s what i wanted to achieve , it is simple i already have data showing , order the data onclick and then update it again so the next time i start the app , the order is saved not ignored

Comment: can you show code for how you are updating db and also the entity? When you update the row in db, it just updates the row and not rearrange it.

Comment: well im showing it above , i create a query which sort the data alphabetically and used live data to observe that data so if the data is rearranged , data should be updated in room , my approach could be wrong , what do you think should be used or f there is any better way to do that thank you

Comment: any help mate regarding my issue

Comment: @takieddine, Did you check the `model_task_name`? What you are passing into the query?